# Route to network via two different (bridged) interfaces

Tags: linux, route, iproute

It is possible to have two different routes to the same destination network via two different interfaces?

I have a network I want to reach: 10.0.0.0/24 from a host with multiple (bridged) interfaces, one of which has an IP in the same network I want to reach ( 10.0.0.10). The other IP is 192.168.0.10.

By changing the routing, I'm able to ping either IP at a time, but I can't find a route/rule that will allow me to ping both IPs from the 10.0.0./24 network (the idea being to have a route/rule based on source network and destination IP).

Comment: I am not sure if I get you correctly, but if one of the IPs is already in the 10.X range, you don't need a route for that. Just add route for the 192.168.x adress

Comment: Thanks, although I had already done that (first thing I did), your comment made look look further into the routing and found the answer. I just needed Reverse Path Filtering on that specific interface.

Answer (score 0):

In my case enabling Reverse Path Filtering for "all" did the trick:

```
echo 2 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/rp_filter
```

In the case of a ping, the ICMP req will come from `vlan 10` (10.0.0.10) and the reply will go via `vlan 19` (192.168.0.10)

edited: I'm replacing the inteface "vlan1" with "all" because the former will only work as long as I manually remove the route to the other network (added by the OS). Using "all" will work even when the route is there.

Comment: It's not enabling it. It's relaxing it from Strict to Loose. See this RFC: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3704#section-2.2 and this Linux entry: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.rst?h=v5.10#n1407 . Obviously the value on your system was 1. It often tells the routes aren't optimally configured. But as long as it works in the end, good for you.